# Options in MUI Select don't appear

Tags: typescript, select, material-ui, menu

I use a react and in modal i have a select from material mui, when i click on arrow ,options dont appear
i try changed zindex but it not help
When i click on arrow all page wiat for ma choose and is not active but i dont have anything to choose

```
const customStyles = {
  overlay: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0',
    bottom: '0',
    zIndex: 1500,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 'auto',
    border: 'none',
    background: 'transparent',
   // WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    outline: 'none',
    width: '80vw',
  },
};
```

```
<Modal
  isOpen={modalIsOpen}
  onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
  onRequestClose={closeModal}
  style={customStyles}
  contentLabel='Example Modal'
>
 
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <FormControl fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
            
              label="Age"

            >
              <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>

          <TextField fullWidth label='Role' value={role} variant='outlined' sx={{ m: 1 }}
                     onChange={(event) => setRole(event.target.value)} />
        </Box>
```

I'm sitting on them for 3 hour and i cant find why options dont appear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.